# Grep for a word within two inverted commas

Tags: awk, grep

How to grep for a word within two inverted commas. The word may contain any number of characters . e.g "two" , "three"

Comment: What do "inverted comma" and "word" mean in this context?  You can get a list of all "words" in an input with `grep -iw '[A-Z_0-9][A-Z_0-9]*'` (not all versions of `grep` support `\w`, so I avoided it).  If you are just looking for the contents of a comma separated list, you could do `sed 's/,/\n/g'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` will show a matching line, so all you have to do is to find the two double-quotes...

```
grep '".*"'
```

If you want to **extract** a word that is within double quotes you can, for example, do...

```
awk 'match($0,/"[^"]*"/) {print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}'
```

Comment: Or use `grep -o` to only show the matching portion of the line (with a non-greedy regex).

Comment: Stephen, you don't need the non-greedy version if you implement the grep regexp as I've done above with awk. But you will get the quotes as part of the output, and the OP spoke about a match **within** the quotes.

Comment: Indeed, it's not quite equivalent; I just thought it might be useful to add that since the `-o` option to `grep` seems to be little-known.

Comment: Stephen, along your thought it's probably also worthwhile to note that with option `-o` multiple matches per line lead to one matched result per output line. So you can just pipe the result into, say, `sed s/\"//g` to get one match per line.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting word(s) following @StephenKitt comment:

```
grep -oP '(?<=")[\w\s]+?(?=")'
```

or

```
grep -oP '(?<=")\w+?(?=")'
```

for single word strings